# Python quiz program - reading CSV and parsing questions/answers

Tags: python

I have a simple quiz in Python that's having issues. It reads a comma-separated text file in "question,answer" format. The program is reading the quiz fine and outputs the questions, but I can't get the questions to randomize and the "CorrectAnswer" variable to read the correct answer.

For instance, if the question is, "What is the capital of California?" and the answer is "Sacramento", the CSV file has it written like this: "What is the capital of California,Sacramento". But the program can't reference the answer, only the first part before the comma.

What am I doing wrong?

```
def quiz():
    score=0
    questionsRight=0
    fileName = input("Please enter the name of the quiz file: ")
    quizFile = open(fileName,"r")
    quizData = quizFile.readlines()
    questionno=1
    for x in range(10):
        for x in quizData:
            data = x.split(",")
        random.shuffle(quizData)
        questions = data[0]
        CorrectAnswer = data[1]

        print("Question #",questionno)
        print(questions)
        answer = input("What is your answer? ")
        if answer == CorrectAnswer:
            print("Correct!")
            score=score+1
            questionsRight=questionsRight+1
            questionno = questionno+1

        else:
            print("Incorrect.")
            questionno = questionno+1

    totalScore = (score / 10) * 100
    print("You got ",score," questions right, and a score of ",totalScore,"%.")
```

Comment: I checked your code, on my sample data it works _almost_ fine - the problem is that `x.split(",")` output end of the line `\n` symbol as well. For example, `data=['q1', 'a1\n']`

Comment: Yeah I saw that too. Any suggestions on how to write it so the \n symbol is ignored?

Comment: @spiritoffire224 see my answer for a more comprehensive solution, but the minimal solution is to simply write `CorrectAnswer = data[1].rstrip()`

Answer (score 2):

There's a stdlib library for this: `csv`.

```
import csv

with open("path/to/your/quizfile.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    quiz_qas = list(reader)  # this could get *very* large -- take care if you have a large file.

q, a = random.choice(quiz_qas)
print(q)
answer = input(">>> ")
if answer == a:
    # user got the right answer
else:
    # user failed
```

`random.sample` will even let you select a random k-size sample of `quiz_qas`.

```
quiz = itertools.sample(quiz_qas, num_questions)
for q, a in quiz:
    # etc
```

Comment: Awesome that's exactly what I was looking for! However, I need to have the user specify an input. fileName = input("Please enter the name of the quiz file: ")

Comment: @spiritoffire224 that's fine -- you can replace that placeholder string `"path/to/your/quizfile.csv"` any way you like, including prompting the user for it first.

Answer (score 0):

- Shuffle the list and pick first `n` lines
- Use `strip` to remove new lines at the end of the answer

Updated code:

```
import random
def quiz():
    score=0
    questionsRight=0
    fileName = input("Please enter the name of the quiz file: ")
    quizFile = open(fileName,"r")
    quizData = quizFile.readlines()
    random.shuffle(quizData)
    questionno=1
    for i in range(5):
        x = quizData[i].strip()
        data = x.split(",")        
        question = data[0]
        CorrectAnswer = data[1]

        print("Question #",questionno)
        print(question)
        answer = input("What is your answer? ")
        if answer == CorrectAnswer:
            print("Correct!")
            score=score+1
            questionsRight=questionsRight+1
            questionno = questionno+1

        else:
            print("Incorrect.")
            print("Correc answer should be: "+CorrectAnswer)
            questionno = questionno+1
        print()

    totalScore = (score / 10) * 100
    print("You got ",score," questions right, and a score of ",totalScore,"%.")
quiz()
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

`data.csv`:

```
Demo question 1,Answer 1
Demo question 2,Answer 2
Demo question 3,Answer 3
Demo question 4,Answer 4
Demo question 5,Answer 5
Demo question 6,Answer 6
Demo question 7,Answer 7
Demo question 8,Answer 8
Demo question 9,Answer 9
Demo question 10,Answer 10
Demo question 11,Answer 11
Demo question 12,Answer 12
Demo question 13,Answer 13
Demo question 14,Answer 14
Demo question 15,Answer 15
Demo question 16,Answer 16
Demo question 17,Answer 17
Demo question 18,Answer 18
Demo question 19,Answer 19
Demo question 20,Answer 20
Demo question 21,Answer 21
```

**Improvement:**

- Use `csv` module. See [Adam Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53567646/3129414).

**Reference:**

- Official documentation on CSV: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html